# Meaning of term "sh*-spit"

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, offensive-language

In movie "[Polar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4139588/)" one character uses an invective "shit-spit" for crime organization boss. What does "shit-spit" mean? Could you provide me some definition or alternative term? I found one definition on Urban Dictionary but I am not sure about it:

> The water that splashes up into your anus when releasing a turd into the shitter.

She calls him like that behind his back basically. But he knows about that because he heard her saying it during her phone call.

Comment: A great deal of English vulgarity does not have a literal meaning (or has a literal meaning which is nonsensical or greatly removed from its actual meaning).

Answer (score 1):

The woman is using

> **shit-spit**

to say that the person is *very undesirable, of no value, and annoying*, the characteristics of **shit-spit**.

It would similar if she called him

> **You worthless piece of shit.**